# Type of service modification for protocol

Tags: networking

I am wondering if modifying TOS octet can affect the speed of the connection. If yes can you give me some examples? Should I use iptables to change it for choosen protocol?

Answer (score 1):

ToS, which is actually outdated because we now use DSCP, is only useful if the intermediate nodes are configured to do something with it, but that is not the default behavior. In fact, there are many network switches that default to changing the ToS/DSCP value to `0` unless they are configured to trust it coming into the switch interface. Also, many switches can be configured to rewrite the DSCP value to what the network administrator determines it should be for the data type.

QoS is a huge subject, and classification and marking of packets is one part. Another part is creating the policies for treatment of the marked packets. Finally, you must implement the policies by configuring the network devices to perform the actions in your policies based on the markings. You may shape, police, queue, etc. packets differently based on the different classifications.

Unless the network devices through which the packet pass are configured to treat marked packets, then changing the markings does nothing. That is why QoS doesn't work over the public Internet. Also, even if QoS is configured on a network, you must know how each marking is treated, which means that you must know what the policies are. For example, simply setting marking that you think is good, may get your packets sent to the back of the line, depending on the way the policies are implemented.